# Let "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" NOT called only when an image within cell is tapped (but make it called otherwise)?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I would like to put an image on my `UITableViewCell`, and make the cell moved to detail view controller when an user taps on the cell. However, I also want to let the cell NOT move to the detail VC when an user taps on the image which is put on only the part of the cell. The cell looks something like the follows:

```
[cell.textLabel     myImage    accessoryType] <- UITableViewCell
```

However, when I implement my code like below, an user must be moved to the detail VC when she taps on the cell, even if she taps on the tiny portion covered by the image. Is it possible to disable the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` when she taps on the image?

#### tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
var cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellReuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

var list = listArray[indexPath.row]
cell.textLabel?.text =  list.name

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DetailButton
let image = UIImage(named: "myImage.png")
var imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(280, 4, 36, 36)
cell.addSubview(imageView)

return cell
```

I tried `imageView.userInteractionEnabled = false` but the result didn't change.

Also note that the image is not accessory view since I also want to use accessory type (both can't be used) so you can't use `tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:` delegate method.

Comment: Try setting `userInteractionEnabled` to true for the image view instead. If that doesn't work, try setting `exclusiveTouch` to true and see if that works.

Comment: @AdamPro13 Tried both but it still didn't work. Thanks for the comment though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to use a UIButton instead of an image view, or overlay the the image with a button.  The button doesn't have to do anything, but will intercept the touch.

Answer (score 5):

You have three approaches to accomplish it:

1. Add `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your `UIImageView`. It will forces the `UITableView` dont call `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` if you tap over `UIImageView`.
2. If you are using storyboard, you can override `override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String!, sender: AnyObject!) -> Bool` and avoid it.
3. Or as @DuncanLowrie said:

   > use a UIButton instead of an image view, or overlay the the image with a button. The button doesn't have to do anything, but will intercept the touch.

Comment: Do these work? For me No.1 didn't work; the tap still responds to `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. I'm not sure how I can set segue to image view in IB. Still not tried No.3, though.

Comment: What have you tryied? show your code.  No.1 has a lot of code that can helps you (google it) https://goo.gl/1WzQKL